# Should I use "Is" or "Are" in a sentence that has two uncountable/abstract nouns as the subject?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct?

1. What **is** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?
2. What **are** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote this answer for a similar question on another forum. I'm adapting it here.

The correct auxiliary verb is **"are"** or **"were"** in the past tense.

The trick is simple here. Let me explain.

If you get confused, look at the sentence

> *What **is/are** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?*

Let us count how many relevant **"nouns"** there are in the part of the sentence that constitutes the necessity of ***"is/are"***.

The following are the nouns / noun phrases:

- Fund manager
- Operating experience
- Track record

> **Note:** For clarity, I am considering groupings of words that make sense
>   in the context, rather than going to the base concepts. In other
>   words, I am skipping a few steps since I understand how these words
>   are grouped together.

Now, all these noun phrases mean different things here. There needs to be a link between them.

So let us look at this part again.

We notice that there is a possessive case here, denoted by the apostrophe and the 's'.

But are they talking about the possession of one person or more than one person?

If they were talking about the possessions of more than one person, this exercise ends here. The verb needs to be plural (i.e., are).

But in this case, we are talking about the possession of a single person. So let us ignore the possessive clause for now.

So we have the phrases:

- Operating experience
- Track record

So these are two things which are very similar to each other. They are related to a profession and the performance of an individual.

But depending on the industry, they are not necessarily the same thing.

So, is there any other connector? **YES!!!**

The word **"and"** is used between the two phrases.

But does it combine the two things into ONE concept?

Again, this depends on your interpretation. But I'm going to consider that ***experience*** concerns a length of time while ***track record*** concerns quality of service.

So I will answer **No**.

We are still talking about **TWO** different things, separately.

So here, the auxiliary verb required is **"are"**. The correct sentence is therefore,

> What ***are*** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?

**NOTE:**

Please remember the method used here:

- Count the number of nouns.
- Connect them if possible.
- Count them again.
- Connect them again.
- and so on....

Answer (score 0):

From Garner's Modern American Usage 3rd Ed:

> **Compound Subjects Joined Conjunctively.** If two or more subjects joined by **and** are different and separable, they take a plural verb:
>
> At the same time, the democratic process and the personal
>   participation of the citizen in his government **are** not all we
>   want. Few golfers appreciate the time, money and technical know-how
>   that **go** into making a golf product.

So, according to the quotation, the second variant is correct: *What **are** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?*

Comment: So which of the two sentences are you going for...?

Comment: the second one, of course

Comment: Interesting.  You should update your answer to make that clear, and we'll see how we compare.

Answer (score 0):

For me, *"Historical operating experience and track record"* is a conceptual singular entity so, in the case of your statements, number #1 is correct—*"What **is** the fund manager's historical operating experience and track record?"*

I note that my answer entirely stems on considering *historical operating experience* and *track record* as two ways of saying the same thing, insofar as I am not a financial professional.  If those are legitimate nouns describing  entirely separate objects within the field of finance, then I would agree with [@MichaelLogin's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/221956/97730).